# $S^{-1}R[(x_i)_{i\in I}]=(S^{-1}R)[(x_i)_{i\in I}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Behold any commutative ring $R$. Is it true that
$S^{-1}R[(x_i)_{i\in I}]=(S^{-1}R)[(x_i)_{i\in I}]$
for any multiplicative subset $R$ of $S$? I couldn't find this in full Bourbaki generality, not even in Bourbaki itself!

Comment: Of course, this is the way to go. but I am not sure whether the isomorphism will be of $S^{-1}R$-algebras or $R$-algebras!

Comment: because $A[x]$ is the free commutative $A$-algebra on $\{x\}$.